# How to fix a list to character matching error in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, error-handling

I am trying to write a function that finds a pair by matching its first component and returns that pair's second component. When one tries to look up a character that does not occur in the cipher key, the function should leave it unchanged. Examples:

```
ghci> lookUp 'B' [('A','F'), ('B','G'), ('C','H')]
'G'
ghci> lookUp '9' [('A','F'), ('B','G'), ('C','H')]
'9'
```

I have a cipher key that I am not sure whether would help, but here it is:

```
alphabet = ['A'..'Z']

makeKey :: Int -> [(Char, Char)]
makeKey k = zip alphabet (rotate k alphabet)
```

That outputs something like this:

```
ghci> makeKey 5
[('A','F'),('B','G'),('C','H'),('D','I'),('E','J'),('F','K'),
('G','L'),('H','M'),('I','N'),('J','O'),('K','P'),('L','Q'),
('M','R'),('N','S'),('O','T'),('P','U'),('Q','V'),('R','W'),
('S','X'),('T','Y'),('U','Z'),('V','A'),('W','B'),('X','C'),
('Y','D'),('Z','E')]
```

This is my code so far:

```
lookUp :: Char -> [(Char, Char)] -> Char
lookUp a xs = [ c | (b,c) <- xs, b == a ]
```

When I try to run it, it produces a list and character mismatch error. How do I fix this?

Comment: You don't want to build a list of results. You want to return a single character whether or not `b == a`. There is a built-in `lookup` function you can make use of: it returns a `Maybe Char`: `Just x` when it finds a match and `Nothing` when it does not.

Comment: With the list, though, you can check if it is empty ( in which case you return `a`) or not (in which case you return its first element).

Comment: using the list comprehension function `lookup` from the answer, you just need to call `head (lookup a xs ++ [a])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *list comprehension* you return a *list* of items. If you thus implement this as:

```
lookUp :: Char -> [(Char, Char)] -> [Char]
lookUp a xs = [ c | (b,c) <- xs, b == a ]
```

you will retrieve a *list* of `Char`acters (a `String`) which contains the second item `c` of the 2-tuples, given the first item `b` of that 2-tuple matches with the query `a`.

But you do not want to retrieve a list, but only the first match, or the same item given the item is not in the list of 2-tuples.

We can implement this for example with recursion where we enumerate over the elements of the list and if we find the given item, we return the second item. If no 2-tuple can be found with as first item the item we are looking for, we return the item we are looking for:

```
lookUp :: Eq a => a -> [(a, a)] -> a
lookUp query = go
    where go [] = …  -- (1)
          go ((xa, xb) : xs)
              | query = xa = …  -- (2)
              | otherwise = …  -- (3)
```

where you need to fill in the `…` parts. For the third case, you will need to recurse on the tail `xs` of the list.

Comment: Alright, I will try my best. What does the query = go part mean?

Comment: @idontknowhowtocode: `query` is the first parameter, so it is the value we are looking for. `go` is a helper function that takes as parameter the list of 2-tuples. This avoids passing the `query` in each recursive call.

Comment: Oh yeah, and the part xa and xb, is it similar to xs?

Comment: @idontknowhowtocode: `xa` and `xb` are respectively the first and second item of the first 2-tuple of the list, whereas `xs` is the list of the remaining 2-tuples.

Comment: @idontknowhowtocode: see http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists